# Unable to perform click or sendkeys in Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I'm trying to click on a button in Android app using Appium but no luck.

Element in UIAutomatorViewer

[image]

Using below code for the same :

**PageClass**

```
public class MyProfilePage 
{
    AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @FindBy(id="com.rawalinfocom.rcontact:id/image_right_left") 
    public WebElement profileEditIcon;

    @FindBy(id="com.rawalinfocom.rcontact:id/input_first_name") 
    public WebElement firstName;

    @FindBy(id="com.rawalinfocom.rcontact:id/input_last_name")  
    public WebElement lastName;

    @FindBy(id="com.rawalinfocom.rcontact:id/button_name_update")   
    public WebElement updateButton;

    @FindBy(id="com.rawalinfocom.rcontact:id/snackbar_text")    
    public WebElement notificationMessage;

    public MyProfilePage(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void clickProfileEditIcon()
    {
        profileEditIcon.click();
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName.getText();
    }

    public void enterFirstName(String name)
    {
        firstName.clear();
        firstName.sendKeys(name);
    }

    public void enterLastName(String name)
    {
        lastName.clear();
        lastName.sendKeys(name);
    }

    public void clickUpdateButton()
    {
        updateButton.click();
    }

    public String getNotificationMessage()
    {
        return notificationMessage.getText();
    }
}
```

And Here testcase class

```
@Test
public void updateFirstNameAndVerifyChanges()
{
    homepage.clickBreadCrumbIcon();
    drawer.clickUsername();
    myprofilepage.clickProfileEditIcon();
    WaitHelper.waitUntilElementGetClickable(driver, myprofilepage.firstName);
    myprofilepage.enterFirstName(reader.getCellData(0, 4, 1));
    myprofilepage.clickUpdateButton();
    WaitHelper.waitUntilElementHasText(driver, myprofilepage.notificationMessage);
    System.out.println(myprofilepage.getNotificationMessage());
}
```

But not able to do even single action (click or send keys) on this activity. Always getting `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: You state that you are trying to click on a button but you never state which button. I reminded you to post an MCVE but you've posted ~70 lines of code. We don't need the full page object and full test, just post the relevant lines of code that you are using to click the button, post the different locator attempts, etc. and any error messages. None of these are unreasonable requests and are all covered in the links I posted above.

Comment: @JeffC The element they're trying to click on is highlighted in a red box in their picture. Their code is not needlessly verbose, that owes to the language in question.

Comment: @Rob The element highlighted in the picture is a text field and not a button. OP stated, `I'm trying to click on a button`. I'm familiar with Java... you don't need 70 lines of code to click a button. The point of an MCVE is to have only the code necessary to reproduce the problem. This is not an MCVE.

Comment: @NarendraR I did see that but it wasn't clear what you were calling an "activity". You should probably clarify the question. There's no need to post your entire class, only the code relevant to an MCVE.

Comment: @JeffC, I have tag `appium` and `android` in my Question and a screen in android called Activity paste `what is activity in android` on google. And if you didn't understand the question. then sorry its not my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution :

Actually the issue was related to the Virtual Device. I was using **NEXUS 5 API 24 Android version 7** virtual device

I've changes to **Google Nexus 6 API 23 Android version 6.0** virtual device and It working fine

Might be device dependent issue

Comment: what is your appium version?

Comment: @akhileshgulati v1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Try code below:

```
public class MyProfilePage 
{
    AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @FindBy(id="image_right_left") 
    public WebElement profileEditIcon;

    @FindBy(id="input_first_name") 
    public WebElement firstName;

    @FindBy(id="input_last_name")  
    public WebElement lastName;

    @FindBy(id="button_name_update")   
    public WebElement updateButton;

    @FindBy(id="snackbar_text")    
    public WebElement notificationMessage;

    public MyProfilePage(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void clickProfileEditIcon()
    {
        profileEditIcon.click();
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName.getText();
    }

    public void enterFirstName(String name)
    {
        firstName.clear();
        firstName.sendKeys(name);
    }

    public void enterLastName(String name)
    {
        lastName.clear();
        lastName.sendKeys(name);
    }

    public void clickUpdateButton()
    {
        updateButton.click();
    }

    public String getNotificationMessage()
    {
        return notificationMessage.getText();
    }
}
```

If still not work use Xpath in place of id in your code.